# MySQL TRIGGER: Delete dependent rows from the same table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I create a trigger in MySQL to delete all rows that depend on that OLD row.
Some menu items can be a sub-menu item, so the field menu_in has the parent item menu_id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEL_MENU_DEPENDENCIES 
 BEFORE DELETE ON menu
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DELETE FROM menu WHERE menu_in = OLD.menu_id;
 END
```

But I get an error:

> General error: 1442 Can't update table 'menu' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

I already try "`AFTER`" but is the same problem.

This are the fields in table:

```
menu_id | menu_in | name
```

I search in Google but I did not find a solution.
It seems that it has to do with the possibility of creating an infinite loop.
But apparently the loop would stop if there are no more rows. Right?

Thank you in advance for all your attention.

EDIT

```
+---------+---------+------+
| menu_id | menu_in | name |
+---------+---------+------+
|    1    |    0    | mn1  |
+---------+---------+------+
|    2    |    0    | mn2  |
+---------+---------+------+
|    3    |    1    | mn3  |
+---------+---------+------+
|    4    |    1    | mn4  |
+---------+---------+------+
|    5    |    4    | mn5  |
+---------+---------+------+
|    6    |    2    | mn6  |
+---------+---------+------+
|    7    |    5    | mn7  |
+---------+---------+------+
```

Imagine that I need to delete row menu_id = 1. It would delete lines 3, 4, 5 and 7. Because they create a chain.
With a trigger in MySQL it would be great to do this. I would need just to delete one row, trigger would do the rest.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some data and table definition

Comment: why not delete where menu_id = something OR menu_in = something ? - no trigger or other code required..

Comment: Btw just listing the column names isn't as helpful as publishing the result of show create table

Comment: Hi @SelVazi thank you. I add the fields of the table.

Comment: @Peter mysql do not allow this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions

Comment: @P.Salmon The question is that I only know menu_id of the row I need to delete and I need to delete all other items that depend from that menu_id. So, I delete one row, then delete the rows that depend on that row, then delete rows that depende on those that where deleted and so on. And the idea is to do this with just onde trigger.

Comment: You could better illustrate by publishing sample data as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon please see the contentt of the question, I added more information. Thank you.

Comment: So that's a recursive delete , just about to quit for the day so you could try searching for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a trigger in MySQL or MariaDB.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/stored-program-restrictions.html says:

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

You could accomplish what you describe by using a foreign key with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions for details.